# Default Modifier of a Class

Tags: c#, access-modifiers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the Default Access Modifiers in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521459/what-are-the-default-access-modifiers-in-c)

When I define a `class` in C#, and don't specify any access modifier which one is the default?  Is it `public` or `protected`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C# if the type is not nested (within other class or struct) and doesn't have access modifier applied it is internal. If it is nested - private.

From C# specification:

> 3.5.1 Declared accessibility
>
> ...
>
> • Types declared in compilation units
>   or namespaces can have public or
>   internal declared accessibility and
>   default to internal declared
>   accessibility.
>   •   Class members can
>   have any of the five kinds of declared
>   accessibility and default to private
>   declared accessibility. (Note that a
>   type declared as a member of a class
>   can have any of the five kinds of
>   declared accessibility, whereas a type
>   declared as a member of a namespace
>   can have only public or internal
>   declared accessibility.)

Comment: thanku mr.Dzmitry huba good explanation thank u? i have another doubt
about static method, variable, class. how these r different from normal class, method and variables

Comment: In terms of default accessibility they are not different from instance members.

Answer (score 0):

It is  [internal]

Comment: thank u alex reitbort for information