# Difference to how declare instance variables

Tags: c#

If I have this class:

```
class G
{
   Texture a, b, c;
}
```

and

```
class F
{
   Texture a;
   Texture b;
   Texture c;
}
```

is there a difference in what access modifier is assigned or both are equivalent and thus how write them is only a style-preference?

Comment: Should be just a style preference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no functional difference; `a`, `b` and `c` will all be declared as `private Texture` fields. (`private` is the default access modifier for members of a class.)

Whether you choose to use one access modifier and type declaration for each one, or for all three, is purely stylistic.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference in C# - just stylistics (I prefer the second one).

In languages such as C and C++, it *would* make a difference with pointers:

```
int* p1, p2, p3;   // p1 is a pointer to int, but p2 and p3 aren't
```

In C# we don't have this problem:

```
int* p1, p2, p3;   // Ok, all three are pointers
int *p1, *p2, *p3;   // Invalid in C#
```

Also, in C++ sometimes `T a, b;` is not equivalent to `T a;` `T b;` even when `T` is not a pointer - that's the case when a coincides with T;

```
T T, X; //T and X are of type T

T T;
T X; //error T is not a type
```

Sorry, I posted more about C++ than about C#, but this is to demonstrate that C# has taken care of potential differences between the two forms which C++ hasn't :)

Answer (score 1):

The result is the same. It's equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

No differences! There is just a style choice.

Answer (score 0):

this is purely stylistic and if you want to know more about access modifiers you can get it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521459/what-are-the-default-access-modifiers-in-c)