# C# : Difference between method types

Tags: c#, methods, static-methods, public-method

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between Public, Private, Protected, and Nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614818/what-is-the-difference-between-public-private-protected-and-nothing)

I have a question :
What is the difference between these method types ?

```
Static , Public , Internal , Protected , const , void
```

Sorry my question may seem awkward to professionals but i really want to understand the difference , and by the way i searched and read articles about them but they are all big and not well described , i just need a nice example for each so i could make decision each time i make a function , because i always start with private void ........

Comment: may duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/2521492/1495442

Comment: The downvotes seem a bit harsh. I can understand `close` votes perhaps, but this seems a question in good faith by someone who couldn't understand the existing answers. I am of course biased by being the accepted answer :-) as it could just be someone dodging homework for all I know but I'm going to put my optimist glasses on today.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your basic method has the following:

```
[access modifier?] [static?] [return type or void] [name] ([parameters?])
```

There's a few extra bits and pieces but that's your start.

**Access Modifiers**

Some of those are access modifiers which control which classes have access (can call) whatever you've put the modifier on.

```
// Anyone can call me
public int SomeMethod() { return 1; } 

// Only classes in the same assembly (project) can call me
internal int SomeMethod() { return 1; } 

// I can only be called from within the same class
private int SomeMethod() { return 1; }

// I can only be called from within the same class, or child classes
protected int SomeMethod() { return 1; }
```

**Static**

`Static` means that the method/variable is shared by all instances of the class. It can be combined with an access modifier from above.

```
public class Test
{
  static int a = 0;
  public int SomeMethod() { a = a + 1; return a; }
}

Test t1 = new Test();
t1.SomeMethod(); // a is now 1
Test t2 = new Test();
t2.SomeMethod(); // a is now 2

// If 'a' wasn't static, each Test instance would have its own 'a'
```

**Void**

`void` just means that you have a method that doesn't return anything:

```
public void SomeMethod() 
{ 
  /* I don't need to return anything */ 
}
```

**const**

`const` means that the variable cannot be modified:

```
const int LIFE = 42;
// You can't go LIFE = 43 now
```

Answer (score 4):

The keywords `public`, `private`, `protected` and (`protected`) `internal`, are called [access modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) and determine who can access a given class and/or its members, which helps in [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) and [abstraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_%28computer_science%29).

The storage modifier (thanks AVD) `static` defines a [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method, property or class, [`const`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b) creates a constant and [`void`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yah0tteb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) indicates a return type of 'nothing'.

While developing, it's normal you start with a `private void DoSomething()`, and only if you can and need to access the method externally, you increase the accessibility. If you expect it to be overridden in the same namespace, you use `protected`. If you're writing a library to be used by another application (in a different namespace), you mark it `public`, and so on.

If you want it to return something at some point, you change `void` to the appropriate type. All of this is (including deciding when to make something static or constant) addressed in most basic OO books and tutorials, try to pick up one.

Comment: Nope! static is called "Storage" modifier.

Answer (score 2):

these are called `Access Modifiers`

> **public**
>
> The type or member can be accessed by any other code in the same
>   assembly or another assembly that references it.
>
> **private**
>
> The type or member can only be accessed by code in the same class or
>   struct.
>
> **protected**
>
> The type or member can only be accessed by code in the same class or
>   struct, or in a derived class.
>
> **internal**
>
> The type or member can be accessed by any code in the same assembly,
>   but not from another assembly.
>
> **protected internal**
>
> The type or member can be accessed by any code in the same assembly,
>   or by any derived class in another assembly.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what CodeCaster said...

void is in the place where the type of the returned value is declared.  Void means that there is no return type in a given method.

const indicates the type is a [constant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173119.aspx) and will be defined once and then not modified.