# Why is my .dll file empty?

Tags: c#, dll

I've created a C# library (Tempates > Visual C# > Windows > Class Library) called `VlcController`, with one class `Controller.cs`, containing one class, started like so,

```
namespace Vlc
{
    class Controller
    {
       // Rest of code..
    }
}
```

When I build it t o a .dll, and include in in a seperate project, it has no issue with `using Vlc;`, but it cannot find the `Controller` class. Is there something I need to do to get my class included in the .dll?

If needed I can upload the .dll too, just ask.

Comment: @Alexei indeed, not quite a duplicate as you're missing a step from this question to that one. I think [Can't see class within DLL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13271858/cant-see-class-within-dll) answers it properly. The [default access modifiers question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521459/what-are-the-default-access-modifiers-in-c?lq=1) explains the background in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class is internal, that is why you do not find it. The default accessor for a class is internal.

This will help:

```
namespace Vlc
{
    public class Controller
    {
       // Rest of code..
    }
}
```

Comment: Well damn, so simple! @AlexeiLevenkov could you expand on that a little please?

Comment: Unspecified access levels default to `internal`.  `internal` means a class is only accessible in the assembly the class in defined.