# Interface Implementation Error

Tags: c#

I'm new to c# programming and I know it's an amateur question so please don't laugh me!

I was declare these interfaces

```
class derived : iInterface3
{
    double[] d = new double[5];
    public override int MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return 5;
        }
        set
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
    int iProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return 5;
        }
    }
    double this[int x]
    {
        set
        {
            d[x] = value;
        }
    }
}
class derived2 : derived
{

}
interface iInterface
{
    int iProperty
    {
        get;
    }
    double this[int x]
    {
        set;
    }
}
interface iInterface2 : iInterface
{ }
interface iInterface3 : iInterface2
{ }
```

even i implement all of members of iInterface to derived class but still i recive this error.

> 'final_exam_1.derived' does not implement interface member
>   'final_exam_1.iInterface.this[int]'. 'final_exam_1.derived.this[int]'
>   cannot implement an interface member because it is not public.

and this

> 'final_exam_1.derived' does not implement interface member
>   'final_exam_1.iInterface.iProperty'. 'final_exam_1.derived.iProperty'
>   cannot implement an interface member because it is not public.

why?

Thanks for your helps in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `public` [access modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) to all members that derive from the class.

By [default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521459/what-are-the-default-access-modifiers-in-c) they will have lower access.

Also, you need to drop the `override`, as there is nothing to override when implementing an interface. Overriding is when there is a *virtual* method that you wish to override.

```
class derived : iInterface3
{
    double[] d = new double[5];

    public int MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return 5;
        }
        set
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }

    public int iProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return 5;
        }
    }

    public double this[int x]
    {
        set
        {
            d[x] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

There are other issues with your code, but those are the reasons why things are not compiling.

Answer (score 0):

Make `iProperty` and the indexer public or use explicit interface implementation. The declaration for explicit implementation would look like this: `int iInterface3.iProperty`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't `override` property `int MyProperty`, because nothing to override. No `int MyProperty` in base `class/interface`.

Answer (score 0):

Yo do have a lot of silly issues

```
    public override int MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return 5;
        }
        set
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
```

since you are implementing from a interface, not a base class / abstract class which already has a virtual member hence the **override** is pointless.

Second issue.

```
    int iProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return 5;
        }
    }
```

inherited property cannot be of type private.

Fixed Code:

```
class derived : iInterface3
{
    readonly double[] d = new double[5];
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return 5;
        }
        set
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }

    public int iProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return 5;
        }
    }

    public double this[int x]
    {
        set
        {
            d[x] = value;
        }
    }
}
class derived2 : derived
{

}
interface iInterface
{
    int iProperty
    {
        get;
    }
    double this[int x]
    {
        set;
    }
}
interface iInterface2 : iInterface
{ }
interface iInterface3 : iInterface2
{ }
```