# void vs private void in C#

Tags: c#, private, void

In C# UI codes, when I create event methods, it gets automatically populated with

```
void simpleButton_click(object sender, Eventargs e)
{
}
```

What's the difference between this simple `void` and `private void`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521459/what-are-the-default-access-modifiers-in-c

Answer (score 14):

None, it's syntactical. By default **members** are `private` while types are `internal`).

Often people add `private` for the sake of consistency, especially when it's in a class or type that has many other members with differing access attributes, such as `protected internal` or `public`.

So the following two files are equivalent:

#### Implicit.cs

```
using System;

namespace Foo
{
    class Car : IVehicle
    {
        Car(String make)
        {
            this.Make = make;
        }

        String Make { get; set; }

        CarEngine Engine { get; set; }

        void TurnIgnition()
        {
            this.Engine.EngageStarterMotor();
        }

        class CarEngine
        {
            Int32 Cylinders { get; set; }

            void EngageStarterMotor()
            {
            }
        }

        delegate void SomeOtherAction(Int32 x);

        // The operator overloads won't compile as they must be public.
        static Boolean operator==(Car left, Car right) { return false; }
        static Boolean operator!=(Car left, Car right) { return true; }
    }

    struct Bicycle : IVehicle
    {
        String Model { get; set; }
    }

    interface IVehicle
    {
        void Move();
    }

    delegate void SomeAction(Int32 x);
}
```

#### Explicit.cs

```
using System;

namespace Foo
{
    internal class Car : IVehicle
    {
        private Car(String make)
        {
            this.Make = make;
        }

        private String Make { get; set; }

        private CarEngine Engine { get; set; }

        private void TurnIgnition()
        {
            this.Engine.EngageStarterMotor();
        }

        private class CarEngine
        {
            private Int32 Cylinders { get; set; }

            private void EngageStarterMotor()
            {
            }
        }

        private delegate void SomeOtherAction(Int32 x);

        public static Boolean operator==(Car left, Car right) { return false; }
        public static Boolean operator!=(Car left, Car right) { return true; }
    }

    internal struct Bicycle : IVehicle
    {
        private String Model { get; set; }
    }

    internal interface IVehicle
    {
        public void Move(); // this is a compile error as interface members cannot have access modifiers
    }

    internal delegate void SomeAction(Int32 x);
}
```

A summary of the rules:

- Types (`class`, `struct`, `enum`, `delegate`, `interface`) defined directly in a `namespace` are `internal` by default.
- Members (Methods, Constructors, Properties, Nested Types, Events) are `private` by default, with two exceptions:

  - Operator-overloads must be explicitly marked `public static`. You will get a compile error if you do not provide an explicit `public` access modifier.
  - Interface members are always `public` and you cannot provide an explicit access modifier.
- In C#, both `class` and `struct` members are `private` by default, unlike C++ where `struct` is `public` by default and `class` is `private` by default.
- Nothing is ever implicitly `protected` or `protected internal` in C#.
- .NET supports "Friend Assemblies" where `internal` types and members are visible to code inside another assembly. C# requires the `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo]` attribute to achieve this. This is not the same thing as C++'s `friend` feature (C++'s `friend` allows a `class`/`struct` to list other classes, structs and free-functions that will have access to its `private` members).

Comment: [Here is the page from the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) on this topic, it lists what the defaults are if you do not put the access modifier on (For classes it could be  `private` or `internal` depending on where the class is declared)

Comment: important to note, This isn't true for everything. Classes have default access modifiers of internal.

Answer (score -4):

**void** means to identified this block of code or procedure as **method** or it won't return any values.  If you see any types rather than void means that the blocked of code or procedure is a function or property

this is method

```
private void DoSomething()
{
...code
}
```

this is function

```
private int DoSomething()
{
..code
return 1
}
```

**private** means the method, function, or property is **not accessible** to outside the class  but can be invoke inside the class itself

**public** means the method, function, or property is **accessible** to outside the class  and can also be invoke inside the class itself

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Harrison, His question is What's the difference between this simple void and private void? Read this from access modifier (Private) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st6sy9xe.aspx and for void see this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yah0tteb.aspx

Comment: The question is about explicitly using the private keyword or not (in which case for a method it's still private.) Your answer is about accessibility based on private vs. public and return value.

Comment: Ok I won't argue you with that, but for me if you understand what it does then the difference/s will also be known.