# what is the default constructor access modifer?

Tags: c#

I am confuse on what is the default constructor access modifier and what does this MSDN statemtn says

```
 If the direct base class does not have an accessible parameterless instance constructor, a compile-time error occurs.
```

Because when i applied this with a test program it fails. I can make an object or class that is inheriting another class thogh there is no exteranal parameerless constructor defined.

```
class A 
{
}
class B : A
{
}
class C
{

    public void main()
    {

        B objB = new B();// as per MSDN here should be the compile time error.

    }
}
```

[[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645608%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)]

Comment: B has an automatically generated public default constructor.

Comment: So you mean in B if i externally make parameterless constructor private then only there will be a compile time error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the Default Access Modifiers in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521459/what-are-the-default-access-modifiers-in-c)

Comment: But the other link answeered by Jon Skeet says
The default access for everything in C# is "the most restricted access you could declare for that member".
Which is contradictory to this MSDN link.

Comment: If a class is internal then also its default constructor is public..

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: I retracted my close vote. I realized just now that the question is actually about the "((default constructor) access modifier)", not about the "(default (constructor access modifier))".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If a class contains no instance constructor declarations, **a default
>   instance constructor is automatically provided**. That default
>   constructor simply invokes the parameterless constructor of the direct
>   base class. If the direct base class does not have an accessible
>   parameterless instance constructor, a compile-time error occurs. If
>   the class is abstract then the declared accessibility for the default
>   constructor is protected. Otherwise, the declared accessibility for
>   the default constructor is public.

In your example, all the classes A, B, C has been created with a **default internal** parameterless constructor.

Since both classes are in the same assembly and are internal with internal constructors by default you are not getting a compilation error. But if you declare a **non-accessible** constructor (e.g. private or protected) in your class B you will get a compilation error in your example.

Comment: A->B->C if any of base class has private constructor it will be compile time error?

Comment: If a class is internal then also its default constructor is public..?

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: I have updated my answer since it was not totally right.

Answer (score 4):

> If the direct base class does **not have an accessible parameterless**
>   instance constructor, a compile-time error occurs.

If a constructor is **not defined** for a class, the compiler will automatically generate a **public** default constructor.

Answer (score 3):

From [Using Constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx)

```
Unless the class is static, classes without constructors are 
given a public default constructor by the C# compiler in order to 
enable class instantiation.
```

Answer (score 3):

The compiler creates parameterless constructor if you don't create one yourself, so as per the MSDN page, your example actually ends up looking like this;

```
class A
{
    public A(): base() {}
}

class B : A
{
    public B(): base() {}
}
```

Your call to `new B()` will ultimately end up calling A's constructor. However, if you created an explicit constructor for A which is private;

```
class A
{
   private A() {}
}

class B : A
{

}
```

Then this translates to;

```
class A
{
   private A() {}
}

class B : A
{
    public B(): base() {}
}
```

Which will fail to compile with an error about A's constructor being inaccessible.

Answer (score 2):

If a constructor is not defined for a class, the compiler will automatically generate a `public` default constructor.

However, if there is a constructor defined *that limits the access*, then the compiler will throw.

for example,  this should throw an exception:

```
class A
{
   private A() {}
}
class B : A
{
}
```