# Is there something known as Private Class

Tags: c#, class

1. If we do not specify Public/Private/Protected, what will it be?
2. Is there something known as a private class?

Answer (score 3):

1: that depends on whether the class is nested or not. A top level class defaults to `internal`. A nested class defaults to `private`.

```
class TopLevelClass {
    class PrivateClass {

    }
}
```

2: yes, but only for nested classes:

```
class TopLevelClass {
    private class ExplicitlyPrivateClass {

    }
    class ImplicitlyPrivateClass {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify `Public/Private/Protected` for a main `class` it will be `internal`, for a nested class the default access specifier will be `private`.

`private class` exists. You can access a `private class` only if it is declared inside another class. Means it is `private` to the parent class as

```
class example //which is default interal
{
      private class ex
      {
      }

      class ex1 //default private
      {
      }
}
```

Comment: "If you don't specify Public/Private/Protected it will be internal." that too, depends on whether the type is nested

Comment: @MarcGravell I have updated :)

Answer (score 1):

1) If no modifier is specified, the visibility will depend on the situation where it is omitted; the topic is discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521459/what-are-the-default-access-modifiers-in-c) question.

2) In the following code, `InnerClass` is `private` in `OuterClass`.

```
namespace ClassTest
{

    class OuterClass
    {
        private class InnerClass
        {
        }

        OuterClass()
        {
            InnerClass Test = new InnerClass();
        }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OuterClass TestOne = new OuterClass();
            InnerClass TestTwo = new InnerClass(); // does not compile
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: " If no modifier is specified, the visibility will be private. " - no, in virtually all cases, the visibility will be `internal`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I wasn't aware of that; answer changed.

Comment: "1) If no modifier is specified, the visibility will be internal." - still wrong, for the reason that you explain in 2

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the hint again; I updated the answer to refer to a related question.

Answer (score 0):

[What are the Default Access Modifiers in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521459/what-are-the-default-access-modifiers-in-c)

and there is a private class but in my opinion its pointless