# Inconsistent accessibility: Base class is less accessible than subclass

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to create an object of RecipeManager in mainForm but I get this error:

> Inconsistent accessibility: base class
>   `'Assign_1.ListManager<Assign_1.Recipe>'` is less accessible than class
>   'Assign_1.Managers.RecipeManager'

RecipeManager:

```
public class RecipeManager : ListManager<Recipe>
    {
        public RecipeManager()
        {

        }
    }
```

ListManager:

```
 public class ListManager<T> : IListManager<T>
    {
        protected List<T> m_list;

        public ListManager()
        {
            m_list = new List<T>();
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get { return m_list.Count; }
        }
```

I have another manager class that works fine:

```
public class AnimalManager : ListManager<Animal>
{
    private int startID =100;

    public AnimalManager()
    {
    }
```

I have all Manager classes in a folder called `Managers`

Comment: Are you sure they all have `public` before the class declaration like you've posted here?

Comment: Recipe isn't public.

Comment: Check accessibility of the interface - should be also public

Comment: @FilipHurta Huh? Interfaces don't need to be public, do they? It's normal for a public class to implement an internal interface.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to make Recipe public

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generic class is as accessible as least accessible of all parameter. So most likely `Recipe` class is not public.

Fix: make sure to declare `Recipe` as `public` explicitly.

Note that omitting accessibility is most likely reason of class not being public - check out [What are the Default Access Modifiers in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521459/what-are-the-default-access-modifiers-in-c) for defaults.

```
class Recipe { ... {
```

means

```
internal class Recipe {....}
```