# Using a variable from a different class and method into another class and method

Tags: c#

This is my main class person

```
public class Person
{
     public void SetAge(int n)
    {
         n = 20;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    }
}
```

and i want to access the n variabe in this inherited class student

```
 class student : Person
{

    public void GoToClasses()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am going to class");
    }
    public void ShowAge()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("My age is {0}",n);
    }
}
```

I tried using Person.n or SetAge(20) or SetAge(n) and it won't work !

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Person
{
    public int Age {get; set;}
}
```

Above represents a basic object.

Use case:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.Age = 25;
```

Other object additions:

```
public class Person
{
    public Date BirthDate {get; set;}
    public int Age { get { return (DateTime.Now.Year - BirthDate.Year); } } //read only
}
```

Comment: I try to keep my object classes as basic as possible. If there is anything that needs logic, I create class to manipulate items. Example. I have a repository class for each object (which objects for me represent a record of data.) So I would have a PersonRepo that does my CRUD operations.

Answer (score 2):

As Andrew pointed out, you don't have a method of accessing that variable. Not only that; class fields default to private access.

Link:[What are the Default Access Modifiers in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521459/what-are-the-default-access-modifiers-in-c)

Andrew wrote you code that gives you a property, which isn't wholly necessary, but it is the easiest way to get getter and setter accessor methods.

If you only wanted your inherited class to have access while still restricting access outside your class, use protected access modifier.

Edit: I misread the question. Not only can you not access the method parameter n from outside the function it's used in, I'm not even sure why you would want to. Just do what Andrew said, and do some research on variable scope.

Comment: Though accurate the note on class fields defaulting to private seems irrelevant since there are no fields so that most certainly is not any part of the problem here (the fact that there are no fields is the bigger problem!).

Comment: The `n` is weirdly enough declared as a parameter of the method. The method is very much not what you expect for a SetAge method (you wouldn't expect it to be deciding the age to set and ignoring the input parameter). The original code is just very confused which makes it tricky to work out which part needs focussing on as an answer (just fixing the problem feels like it would probably leave the OP still confused about other concepts demonstrated here.

Comment: That's kinda where I ended up after I read it again. Af this point, OP would be better served by an introductory OOP class than anything I can type, and I'm not trying to be mean.

Comment: I quite agree! This is why I didn't answer at all.

Comment: @RonThompson, I agree. However I think that OP may already be in class and was introducted to SO, which in my opinion is a good thing for any developer to learn (easy, or hard way) how to utilize SO to their advantage.

Comment: Thanks for your concern regarding me . I have just started learning c# but it was in the practice exercise that i was trying to do..  http://practiceexercisescsharp.blogspot.in/2013/05/601-classes-student-teacher.html .. Now i understand it a bit better .. Thanks for your effort ! :)

Comment: Oh no hard feelings. I just don't know where to start to help you.

Answer (score 1):

`n` is not an exposed property of `Person`. You can either expose it or return an `int` from your `SetAge(int n)`.

Exposing n:

```
public int n {get; set; }
```

Returning an int:

```
public int SetAge(int n)
{
    // this is not the normal way to set via a method. you don't normally
    // set the input variable to a static value like this.
    n = 20;
    return n; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your base class:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Age {get; set;}
}
```

Here is your inherited class:

```
class student : Person
{
    public void ShowAge()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("My age is {0}",Age);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the "n" variable first in the Person class.
Try this:

```
public class Person
{
    public int n;
    public void SetAge()
    {
        n = 20;
    }

static void Main(string[] args)
   {

   }
}
```

You shouldn't set the parameter of the method "SetAge(int n)" when you later change this parameter. It's pointless in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your n variable as a class field with either protected or public visibility.
Like this:

```
public class Person
{
    protected int n;

    public void SetAge(int n)
    {
         n = 20;
    }
}
```

Or you could use a public property as the other answers showed already

```
public class Person
{
    public int Age {get; set;}
}
```

This way in the student class you could use it like this

```
public class Student : Person
{
    public void ShowAge()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("My age is {0}", Age);
    }
}
```

or like this

```
public class Student : Person
{
    public void ShowAge()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("My age is {0}", n);
    }
}
```