# Error: Cannot implement an interface member because it is not public

Tags: c#, interface

I am getting this error:

> Error  27  'HelloIBCSharp.EWrapperImpl' does not implement interface member 'IBApi.EWrapper.accountDownloadEnd(string)'. 'HelloIBCSharp.EWrapperImpl.accountDownloadEnd(string)' cannot implement an interface member because it is not public.    C:\Users\diddy\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\HelloIBCSharp\HelloIBCSharp\EWrapperImpl.cs    9   11  HelloIBCSharp

tutorial says to "These errors indicate that EWrapperImpl is not implementing all of the methods declared in the EWrapper interface. In order to proceed, you need to provide at least an empty shell of all methods declared in EWrapper."

in my class where i implement EWrapper how do i provide empty shell of all methods.

Comment: this is in EWrapper.cs "void accountDownloadEnd(string account);" 
In my EWrapperImpl.cs i am doing this " void accountDownloadEnd(string account) { }" , do i need to add public

Answer (score 1):

Sharing your code would help you get an answer.

However, in this case, the answer is exactly what the error says: your method `accountDownloadEnd` is not marked `public` (i.e. it is either explicitly declared `private`, `protected` or `internal`, or there is no scope given at all). Mark it `public` and your code (at least for this method) will compile.

Comment: this is in EWrapper.cs "void accountDownloadEnd(string account);"
in my EWrapperImpl.cs i am doing this "
        void accountDownloadEnd(string account) { }" , do i need to add public

Comment: @user149169 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521459/what-are-the-default-access-modifiers-in-c

Comment: @user149169: Yes; add `public`. It's `private` by default (as per Alexei's link).

Comment: thank you Dan and Alexei