# Inconsistent accessibility parameter type

Tags: c#, .net, access-modifiers

I've been fighting over this error because I've alredy read lots of questions in this blog but unfortunately, none of them have helped me.

The answers of those question say that the **class** in which the error is being held, **should be public**, and that *seems to solve the problem*. But all my classes are public, so I don't know which the problem or error is.

> Error: Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type
>   'Parqueo.ClaseEmpleado' is less accessible than method
>   'Parqueo.FormMenuAdmin.FormMenuAdmin(Parqueo.ClaseEmpleado)'

Here is a my code:

```
namespace Parqueo
{
    public partial class FormMenuAdmin : Form
    {
        public ClaseEmpleado Empleado = new ClaseEmpleado();

        public FormMenuAdmin(ClaseEmpleado _Empleado) //'FormMenuAdmin' is marked as the red errod
        {
             Empleado = _Empleado;
             InitializeComponent();            
         }
         private void FormMenuAdmin_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             //label1.Text = "Bienvenido" + Empleado._Nombre;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error says that the `ClaseEmpleado` class needs to be public.

Comment: Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521459/what-are-the-default-access-modifiers-in-c (also can't be really closed as such since current question missing information to diagnose problem).

Answer (score 1):

Where's the code for the class ClaseEmpleado? That class should be public.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: I asked a question but I also gave the answer because there was no other option, the compiler was statement that the access modifier of the parameter should be public.

Answer (score 0):

```
public FormMenuAdmin(...)
```

is a public constructor, i.e. something that could be used by anyone.

However, the parameter passed to the constructor

```
ClaseEmpleado _Empleado
```

is of a type that is not public and therefore is not available to anyone.

Conclusion: make `ClaseEmpleado` public for everyone so that it can be passed to the constructor, otherwise it's impossible to use the constructor.