# C# Main runs without being public

Tags: c#

why is Main not public in C#, in java it gives an error if we don't have main as public, how does the system call the Main in C#?

Comment: The spec says it can.

Comment: @user1666620 The main method is a method, which has a default of **private**. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2521492/261050)

Comment: @Maarten thanks for the correction.

Comment: Well, of course it *should* be private.  Calling Main() is pretty unlikely to turn out well.

Comment: @HansPassant, that's an interesting way of looking at it. Never thought of making `Main` private before, but what you say makes sense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the [source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9184c55b-4629-4fbf-ad77-2e96eadc4d62/why-is-main-in-c-not-a-public-static-?forum=csharpgeneral):

> The CLR doesn't actually mind if your method is private or public.  It
>   doesn't invoke it through the use of normal C# code.  Here's what the
>   native call stack looks like if you're interested:
>
> ```
> 00000000`0014ea10 00000642`7f67d4a2 0x642`80150142
> 00000000`0014ea90 00000642`7f5108f5 mscorwks!CallDescrWorker+0x82
> 00000000`0014eae0 00000642`7f522ff6 mscorwks!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0xe5
> 00000000`0014eb80 00000642`7f49a94b mscorwks!MethodDesc::CallDescr+0x306
> 00000000`0014edb0 00000642`7f474ae4 mscorwks!ClassLoader::RunMain+0x23f
> 00000000`0014f010 00000642`7f5efb1a mscorwks!Assembly::ExecuteMainMethod+0xbc
> 00000000`0014f300 00000642`7f467d97 mscorwks!SystemDomain::ExecuteMainMethod+0x492
> 00000000`0014f8d0 00000642`7f482c24 mscorwks!ExecuteEXE+0x47
> ```
>
> The address at the top is your Main method.