# Can validation be coded in the class with the following error? Inconsistent Accessibility: Parameter Type Is Less Accessible Than Method

Tags: c#, class, validation, methods

My project has 3 classes. A form class with a textbox and a datetimepicker, a class called BuildingPermit and a class called Validator.

I'm using the Validator class to have handle generic data validation such as throwing an error whether or not the text box is blank or has enough characters.

I'd also like like to create a method in the Validator class that compares the values in the text box to a list of values to see if it already exists.  I've written the method below and I'm getting an inconsistent accessibility error.

Can you please help me understand why I'm still getting the error when I change the building permit class access to internal?  Or would I have to handle the validation directly in the form?

Thanks

```
      public static bool IsUniquePermit(TextBox textbox, List<BuildingPermit> buildingPermitList)
    {
        foreach (BuildingPermit bp in buildingPermitList)
        {
            if (textbox.Text == bp.permitNo)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("That permit number has been previously issued");
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

For reference, the BuildingPermit class is below.

```
  class BuildingPermit
{
    DateTime _issuanceDate;
    string _permitNo;

    public BuildingPermit(DateTime issuanceDate, string permitNo)
    {
        _issuanceDate = issuanceDate;
        _permitNo = permitNo;
    }


    public DateTime issuanceDate
    {
        get
        {
            return _issuanceDate;
        }

        set
        {
            _issuanceDate = value;
        }
    }

    public string permitNo
    {
        get
        {
            return _permitNo;
        }
        set
        {
            _permitNo = value;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The thing is you're declaring a public method that expects a list of something that is internal

Comment: Did you manage to solve your issue?

Comment: Yes I ended up making the class public

Answer (score 1):

The default class access level is `internal` if not specified. Assuming that the class that has the `IsUniquePermit` method is public, then you're exposing the `BuildingPermit` class as part of your public API, but the class isn't available. Short answer is to make `BuildingPermit` public.

More info about it is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2521492/149436

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Interface, that is public and keep the class internal.

```
public interface IBuildingPermit
{

    public DateTime issuanceDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string permitNo
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Implement it to your class:

```
class BuildingPermit : IBuildingPermit
{
    DateTime _issuanceDate;
    string _permitNo;

    public BuildingPermit(DateTime issuanceDate, string permitNo)
    {
        _issuanceDate = issuanceDate;
        _permitNo = permitNo;
    }


    public DateTime issuanceDate
    {
        get
        {
            return _issuanceDate;
        }

        set
        {
            _issuanceDate = value;
        }
    }

    public string permitNo
    {
        get
        {
            return _permitNo;
        }
        set
        {
            _permitNo = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And change the Method like this:

```
public static bool IsUniquePermit(TextBox textbox, List<IBuildingPermit> buildingPermitList)
    {
        foreach (IBuildingPermit bp in buildingPermitList)
        {
            if (textbox.Text == bp.permitNo)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("That permit number has been previously issued");
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
}
```