# Can't get MySql string working from other cs file

Tags: c#, mysql

i try to connect with my MySql connection in a other `.cs` file but i cant reach the connection string `con` which is located in the `MySQL.cs` here is the code i am using:

`MainPage.cs`

```
Data_Layer.MySQL mm = new Data_Layer.MySQL();

        private async void LoginKlik(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
              mm.con.Open();
            }
         catch
         {}
         finally
         {}
```

I am getting a red line under the line `mm.con.Open();` with the statement `inaccisebale due protection level`

`MySQL.cs`

```
namespace VerlofXamarin.Data_Layer
{
    public class MySQL
    { 
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=arabig.nl;Port=3306;database=arabignl_project;User Id=arabignl_project;Password=JariR0800;charset=utf8");
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to read a good tutorial on C# and understand what is the scope of a variable and how to make that variable public

Comment: @Steve and when not to :)

Comment: @MarcGravell sure that also

Answer (score 1):

As  Sebastian Hofmann pointed c# declares fields as private by default. Like MySqlConnection con doesn't have a modifier is private, change it to public and will be accecible.

```
public MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=arabig.nl;Port=3306;database=arabignl_project;User Id=arabignl_project;Password=JariR0800;charset=utf8");
```

An extended explanation about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521459/what-are-the-default-access-modifiers-in-c)

More  [info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers) of access modifiers

Comment: That's not correct. C# implicitely declares all variables private, if not specified. If it was internal, it would be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
public MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=arabig.nl;Port=3306;database=arabignl_project;User Id=arabignl_project;Password=JariR0800;charset=utf8");
```