# What is the accessibility of the backing fields of auto-implemented properties?

Tags: c#, private, encapsulation, accessor

The backing fields are automatically private - am I right?

```
class Car
{
    public String Mark { get; set; }
    public String Model { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by automatically private?

Comment: Are you asking if the properties with `public` access modifiers are `private`?  Or if the class is `private`?  Or something else?

Comment: Properties `Mark` and `Model` are auto-implemented properties and by default they can access private fields.

Comment: Behind the public Properties do we have fields (string mark and string model) ? Are they private?

Comment: Yes in behind compiler create private backing field.

Answer (score 3):

Auto-implemented properties:

```
public String Mark { get; set; }
public String Model { get; set; }
```

When you declare a auto-implemented as shown in your example, the compiler creates a private, anonymous backing field that can only be accessed through the property's get and set accessors.

```
private string mark;
private string model;
public String Mark { 
   get
   {
   return mark;
   }
   set
   {
   mark = value;
   }
}
public String Model{ 
   get
   {
   return model;
   }
   set
   {
   model = value;
   }
}
```

Comment: Well, they won't be named `mark` and `model`, but yes, other then that this answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
class Car
{
    public string Mark { get; set; }
    string Model { get; set; }
}
```

- The class `Car` is internal.
- The property `Mark` is public.
- The property `Model` is private.

---

The comments seem to indicate that you are asking about the accessibility of the backing fields.

Both properties are [Auto-Implemented Properties (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) having a hidden, non-accessible backing field. The documentation for C# auto-implemented properties says:

> When you declare a property [...], the compiler creates a private, anonymous backing field that can only be accessed through the property's get and set accessors.

This is different in VB where the backing field is accessible from within the class: [Auto-Implemented Properties (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/auto-implemented-properties).

Also see: [What are the default access modifiers in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521459/what-are-the-default-access-modifiers-in-c)