# Error CS0122: 'XXX' is inaccessible due to its protection level (CS0122) (tests)

Tags: c#, class

This is my project. I want to call delete_created_page file code in program.cs file, But I have some errors.

Attached image my progect. 
https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/photo/103928744837695537992/6652781093994177394

> 'DeleteCreatedPage.MainDeletePage()' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Help me please. I am beginner in C#, I am using monodevelop and usng Ubuntu 18.04 OS

This is the Delete_created_page.cs file

```
namespace DeletePage
{
    public class DeleteCreatedPage
    {
        static void MainDeletePage()
        {
            //Initialize TestName and ToolName. 
            string testName = "delete_page";
            string toolName = "editor";
            // Calling necessary classes
       }
    }
}
```

And this is the Program.cs file

```
namespace ProgramList
{
    public class MainClass
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DeletePage.DeleteCreatedPage del = new DeletePage.DeleteCreatedPage();
            del.MainDeletePage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a public accessor to `static void MainDeletePage()` to make it `public static void MainDeletePage()`

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of issues stacked together here.

The first is that the method is set to the most restrictive it can, if not explicitly defined, such as `internal`, or `private`. You want it to be public, so be sure to include that.

The second issue is that it is `static`, meaning it is not accessed through an instantiated object, rather it is called directly through the class, like so `DeleteCreatedPage.MainDeletePage()`. If you want the method to work with class members of the specific `DeleteCreatedPage` object, remove `static`. If you want the method to use the same values for every object, leave static on there.

So you have two options to fix this particular problem.

Either change the method definition to this

```
public void MainDeletePage()
```

or change how you call it to this (while still adding `public` to the method definition)

```
DeleteCreatedPage.MainDeletePage()
```

Comment: you will still need to make the static method public with the second solution.

Comment: this is true, I'll edit to make that clear

Comment: I changed, wtat you asked,,
namespace DeletePage
{
    public class DeleteCreatedPage
    {
        public void MainDeletePage()
        {

and in program file.   DeleteCreatedPage.MainDeletePage();
But I have a error yet.. see atached file.  https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/photo/103928744837695537992/6652790747407093154?authkey=COLJ4fOTtZCZEw

Comment: Now its working, when I writing this. public void MainDeletePage()
and in program.cs file called it this.            DeletePage.DeleteCreatedPage del = new DeleteCreatedPage();
            del.MainDeletePage();

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to call `MainDeletePage`, you must mark it as `public` so that other classes can see it.  So, instead of `static void MainDeletePage()` try `public static void MainDeletePage()`.  By default, C# defaults to private scope for a method if it does not explicitly define it's scope.  Private methods can only be accessed by the class in which they are defined.

Comment: Actually, class members default to private, classes default to internal.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521459/what-are-the-default-access-modifiers-in-c

Comment: @Kyle Noted and corrected.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's because MainPageDelete isn't public, you need to write it like this.  The default accessibility modifier for class members is private, so it's not accessible outside of the class.

```
public static void MainDeletePage()
    {
        //Initialize TestName and ToolName. 
        string testName = "delete_page";
        string toolName = "editor";
        // Calling necessary classes
   }
```

Comment: No, it's not help me. :(

Comment: Ummm, that is exactly what that error means.

Comment: my file /delete_created_page/ and program.cs files is differant folders, when I calling a class in properties folder its work fine. but my file in properties/content_editor/editor folder

Answer (score 0):

Now its working, when I writing this in delete_created_page file.

```
public void MainDeletePage()
```

And in program.cs file called it this method.

```
DeletePage.DeleteCreatedPage del = new DeleteCreatedPage();    del.MainDeletePage();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for everyone!