# Since when C# enums can be private?

Tags: c#, enums, access-modifiers

I thought it's impossible but somehow you CAN add modifier to `enum` different than `public`.

This code works perfectly fine and acts as actual private member (inaccesible outside containing class `C`:

```
namespace N {
    public class C {
        private enum E { ... }
    }
}
```

According to @Ben's answer [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521459/what-are-the-default-access-modifiers-in-c/3175697#3175697) this should be impossible:

> **Short answer:** minimum possible access (cf Jon Skeet's answer).
>
> **Long answer:**
>
> ***Non-nested* types, enumeration and delegate accessibilities** (*may only have internal or public accessibility*)
>
> > ```
> >                      | Default   | Permitted declared accessibilities
> > ------------------------------------------------------------------
> > namespace            | public    | none (always implicitly public)
> >
> > enum                 | public    | none (always implicitly public)
> >
> > interface            | internal  | public, internal
> >
> > class                | internal  | public, internal
> >
> > struct               | internal  | public, internal
> >
> > delegate             | internal  | public, internal
> > ```
>
> ***Nested* type and member accessiblities**
>
> > ```
> >                      | Default   | Permitted declared accessibilities
> > ------------------------------------------------------------------
> > namespace            | public    | none (always implicitly public)
> >
> > enum                 | public    | none (always implicitly public)
> >
> > interface            | public    | none
> >
> > class                | private   | All¹
> >
> > struct               | private   | public, internal, private²
> >
> > delegate             | private   | All¹
> >
> > constructor          | private   | All¹
> >
> > interface member     | public    | none (always implicitly public)
> >
> > method               | private   | All¹
> >
> > field                | private   | All¹
> >
> > user-defined operator| none      | public (must be declared public)
> > ```
> >
> > ¹ All === public, protected, internal, private, protected internal
> >
> > ² structs cannot inherit from structs or classes (although they can, interfaces), hence protected is not a valid modifier
>
> The accessibility of a nested type depends on its accessibility
>   domain, which is determined by both the declared accessibility of the
>   member and the accessibility domain of the immediately containing
>   type. However, the accessibility domain of a nested type cannot exceed
>   that of the containing type.
>
> Note: CIL also has the provision for *protected and internal* (as
>   opposed to the existing protected "or" internal), but to my knowledge
>   this is not currently available for use in C#.
>
> ---
>
> See:
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cx03xt0t.aspx   (Man I love
>   Microsoft URIs...)

Comment: Members of the enum cannot have access modifiers applied.  From your link:  "Enumeration **members** are always public, and no access modifiers can be applied."   The enum itself can be made private.

Comment: You can think of the nested enum type as a member of its parent class, and all access modifiers are allowed on members of a class.

Comment: Hi, I rolled back your revision because it removed the context of the question.

Answer (score 6):

That's describing the accessibility of *members* of an `enum`, not the `enum` itself.  All of the *members* of the enum can not be given accessibility modifiers, and are always public.

So you can't do this:

```
public enum Foo
{
    public SomeValue = 1,
    internal AnotherValue = 2,
}
```

`SomeValue` and `AnotherValue` will always be implicitly public.