# How to call GetTickCount64() from Kernel32.dll using PowerShell on Windows 10

Tags: powershell, dllimport

I'm trying to get the uptime of the system in ticks. I want to use a 64 bit method specifically to avoid the wrap-around that happens under the 32 bit version. I know there are other ways to see an uptime but I'm not using those as they cause other issues for my implementation.

I'm trying to use [GetTickCount64()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-gettickcount64) from Kernel32.dll as this should give me what I want.

```
$MethodDefinition = @"
[DllImport("kernel32")] extern static UInt64 GetTickCount64();
"@

$Kernel32 = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $MethodDefinition -Name 'Kernel32' -Namespace 'Win32' -PassThru

$Kernel32::GetTickCount64()
```

Unfortunately running this code gives me the following error:

> WARNING: The generated type defines no public methods or properties.
> Method invocation failed because [Win32.Kernel32] does not contain a method named 'GetTickCount64'.

I don't understand why this doesn't work on Windows 10, this method has been available since Vista.

**Why can't this method be located?**

Comment: update method def to `[DllImport("kernel32")] public extern static UInt64 GetTickCount64();` (notice the `publice` access modifier in front of `extern`)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Well I feel stupid. Please can you make this an answer and I'll accept when I can? Thank you.

Comment: Ahh didn't see this. I guess it don't matter if extern or static is listed first - either worked for me.

Comment: @DougMaurer Yeah, from a syntactical point of view the `public`, `extern`, and `static` keywords are all [modifiers in this context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#methods), you can specify them in any order you like

Comment: Thanks @iiresetme - btw, you're awesome! Still waiting on that pscache talk.. you know, the one that ran out of time. Did you end up doing it again anywhere?

Comment: @DougMaurer Hehehe, yes I did manage to [publish a preview version](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSCache/0.1.1-alpha1) with some of the new eviction policies, more details on GitHub if you're interested. Hit me up on Twitter or file a GH issue if you have any features in mind :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you omit an explicit access modifier in a C# method signature, it [defaults to `private`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2521492/712649), meaning you won't be able to invoke the method via `$Kernel32::GetTickCount64()`, hence the warning.

Fixing it is easy, simple supply the `public` access modifier explicitly:

```bsh
$MethodDefinition = @"
[DllImport("kernel32")]
public extern static UInt64 GetTickCount64();
"@
```

*(I find these import signatures easier to read when the `DllImport` attribute sits above, no functional difference)*

Answer (score 3):

Mark the method as public, this should work

```
$MethodDefinition = @"
[DllImport("kernel32")] public static extern UInt64 GetTickCount64();
"@

$Kernel32 = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $MethodDefinition -Name 'Kernel32' -Namespace 'Win32' -PassThru

$Kernel32::GetTickCount64()
```

Output

```
4059006625
```