# Why do I get "inconsitent accesibilty:paramater type... is less accesable than method" error when all parameters are public?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I am passing a list of objects I have added to into a new form through its constructor and this is where the error is shown

```
public FindRoute(List<AddedLocation> AddedLocation)
    {

        ...
        
    }
```

here is the class which it is based on

```
class AddedLocation
{
    public string name;
    public string PlaceID;

    public AddedLocation(string _name,string _PlaceID)
    {
        name = _name;
        PlaceID = _PlaceID;
    }
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your class declaration from `class AddedLocation` to `public class AddedLocation`. Since you have not declared a protection level, it defaults to `internal` which is less accessible than `public`, which is what your constructor is declared.

Please see [what-are-the-default-access-modifiers-in-c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521459/what-are-the-default-access-modifiers-in-c#:%7E:text=Class%20and%20Struct%20Accessibility&text=Internal%20is%20the%20default%20if,public%2C%20internal%2C%20or%20private.)